Can you "slice" a triangular number into three equal slices?
Problem statement:

Does there exist positive integers $a<b<c$ such that
$$1 + 2 + \dots + (a-1) = (a+1) + \dots + (b-1) = (b+1) + \dots + c?$$
(Note that $a$ and $b$ are not in the sums.)

Motivation: this puzzle (some progress is made).
Notable progress: Gareth McCaughan proved using Pell's equations that if a solution exists, then $c>10^{600000}$. Techniques using elliptic curves were also developed.
Remark: This reminds of this easy-to-state Diophantine equation with large solutions (MO link).

is there a reason to omit $a$ and $b$ from the question (other than the original motivation)?

@BenjaminDickman this question is equivalent to the motivation, so no, at the moment.

This is just an equivalent formulation:
Find squares in the linear recurrence sequence (besides first two terms):
$$9, 25, 481, 14961, 500889, 16973353, \dotsc$$
which can be described equivalently by

recurrence $t_n = 41 t_{n-1} - 246 t_{n-2} + 246 t_{n-3} - 41 t_{n-4} + t_{n-5}$ for $n\geq 5$;
generating function $$\frac{9 - 344x + 1670x^2 - 824x^3 + 33x^4}{(1-x)(1-6x+x^2)(1-34x+x^2)}$$
explicit formula $$t_n = \frac38 \big((1+\sqrt2)^{4n} + (1-\sqrt2)^{4n}\big) + \frac{4-\sqrt2}2 (1+\sqrt2)^{2n} + \frac{4+\sqrt2}2 (1-\sqrt2)^{2n} + \frac{17}4.$$

Suppose that $t_n=z^2$ for some integer $z$, then values of $a,b,c$ are given by
$$\begin{cases} 
a = \frac{(1+\sqrt2)^{2n} - (1-\sqrt2)^{2n}}{4\sqrt2}; \\
b = \frac{(1+\sqrt2)^{2n} + (1-\sqrt2)^{2n} + 2}{4}; \\
c = \frac{z-1}2.
\end{cases}$$

I believe it is a hard question to determine squares in linear recurrences like that. It is more or less solved only for recurrences of the second order (like Fibonacci numbers).

It's hard to find squares in the recurrence, but to lower bound them it's quite straightforward to test for quadratic residues against a number of small primes. Using the $24$ largest primes under $10^6$ for a first filter and then testing any which pass that against odd primes from 3 until rejection, with 3 hours of runtime I calculate that $n > 8000000000$, which gives a lower bound for $c$ on the order of $10^{12248800000}$.
